# React Native: nextState.routes.forEach undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am building a mobile app in React Native and one thing I have problems with is navigation. Right now I am trying to implement a login screen with a main screen from which I can logout or call other screens. For that, and since I use redux, I tried to tweak my StackNavigator and to make a reducer for it and a separate Component. But after I finished doing this I encountered this error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating nextState.routes.forEach)
```

This error is triggered in my code in the connect function from App.js, function that must map some state variables to the Navigation Component. Here is my code:

NavReducer.js

```
import { NavigationActions, StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import routes from "../core/routes";


export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(routes)
const routerForLogin = AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Login')
const routerForPlane = AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('PlaneList')
const loginState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(routerForLogin);
const registerState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Register'));
const planeListState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(routerForPlane);
const insertState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Insert'));

export const navReducer = (state = { loginState, planeListState, insertState, registerState }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case '@@redux/INIT':
      return {
        ...state,
        planeListState: AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(routerForPlane, loginState)
      };

    case 'LOGIN':
      return {
        ...state,
        planeListState: AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(routerForPlane, loginState)
      };

    case 'LOGOUT':
      return {
        ...state,
        loginState: AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
          NavigationActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' })]
          })
        )
      };

    case 'REGISTER':
      return {
        ...state,
        registerState: AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state.registerState)
      };

    case 'INSERT':
      return {
        ...state,
        insertState: AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state.insertState)
      };

    default:
      return {
        ...state,
        planeListState: AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state.planeListState)
      };
  }
};
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';
import authReducer from './src/reducers/LoginReducer';
import registerReducer from './src/reducers/RegisterReducer';
import planeReducer from './src/reducers/PlaneListReducer';
import insertReducer from './src/reducers/InsertReducer';
import Expo from 'expo';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
import { navReducer,AppNavigator } from './src/reducers/NavReducer';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { nav, dispatch } = this.props;

    const state = AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
      ? this.props.nav.planeListState
      : this.props.nav.loginState;

    return (
      <AppNavigator
        screenProps={{ store: { store } }}
        navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
          dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
          state: this.props.nav
        })}
      />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  nav: state.nav
});

const AppWithNavigationState = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

const initialState = {
  auth: { isLoading: false, error: null, username: '', password: '' },
  insert: { wasInserted: false }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers
  (
  {
    nav: navReducer, auth: authReducer, register: registerReducer, planeList: planeReducer, insert: insertReducer
  }
  );

let store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default function Root() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppWithNavigationState />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Routes.js

```
import LoginComponent from "../components/Login";
import RegisterComponent from "../components/Register";
import PlaneListComponent from "../components/PlaneList";
import InsertComponent from "../components/Insert";

const Routes = {
    Login: { screen: LoginComponent },
    Register: { screen: RegisterComponent },
    PlaneList: { screen: PlaneListComponent },
    Insert: { screen: InsertComponent }
};

export default Routes;
```

what is wrong with my code that it triggers that error? Thank you.

Comment: Having this exact same problem: I'm using [hackernoon's guide on this as a reference](https://hackernoon.com/a-comprehensive-guide-for-integrating-react-navigation-with-redux-including-authentication-flow-cb7b90611adf), and I'm stuck on this exact point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your code, I think the problem is your **navReducer**

I suggest you to change your navReducer name to another and combind it and create new Reducer name navReducer like this.

```
const navReducer = (state, action) => {
  const newState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);

  // Simply return the original `state` if `nextState` is null or undefined.
  return newState || state;
};
```

I also push my react-native-redux-example on my Repository on Github
https://github.com/chen2584/react-native-redux-example

Hope this help!

Comment: What specifically is the problem with his nav reducer?

Answer (score 1):

Having just waded my way through the same error message:

In the `render` method of `App`, you define

```
const state = AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
  ? this.props.nav.planeListState
  : this.props.nav.loginState;
```

But the `addNavigationHelpers` prop inside `AppNavigator` is being being passed the parameter `state: this.props.nav`.

My guess is that you meant to pass in the `state` you defined earlier (which you aren't currently using). Try this instead:

```
<AppNavigator
  screenProps={{ store: { store } }}
  navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
    dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
    state
  })}
/>
```